# Charged pion decay and spin conservation

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, conservation-laws, weak-interaction, pions

Charged pions $\pi^\pm$ decay via an intermediate $W$ to (e.g.) a lepton-neutrino pair.

The pions being scalar (spin-0) particles and the intermediate $W$ having spin 1, how is spin conserved in this interaction?

Comment: Aren't the spins of the lepton and the neutrino both $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, they are. But my question is not about spin conservation between initial and final state, but in between.

Comment: The same question has been asked here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89684/angular-momentum-conservation-in-pion-decay