# Angular momentum conservation in pion decay?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, conservation-laws, pions

I have seen the charged pion decay $$\pi^{-}~\to~ \bar{\nu}_{\ell} +\ell^{-}$$ represented with diagrams containing a $W^-$ in the $s$-channel.  The $\pi^-$ and $W^-$ have angular momentum $0$ and $1$ respectively, though. How does this process conserve angular momentum?

I see that this question has been asked before, but I haven't found an answers.

Answer (score 3):

The W is massive so can be in the spin 0 state (or $s=-1, 0, 1$ in general). The photon is massless so does not have this "longitudinal" polarization. For the massive vector boson, the relevant symmetry group is the little group $SO(3)$, and for the photon it is $SO(2,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that only deals with the quantum number $J_z$.  I am asking about how $J$ is conserved.

Comment: I suspect that what's happening is that the W boson couples to some current $J^\mu$ that is a composite of the fields that make up the $\pi$, and it is this that that has spin 1...

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the diagram](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/piondec.html) you are discussing:

[image: charged pion decay]

It seems you are worried by the angular momentum carried by the W+. The W+ is a virtual particle in this reaction.

In virtual paths the particle is off mass shell and its mass is unphysical, and angular momentum as a part of  a four vector  will be a complicated function also having unphysical measure, so conservation of angular momentum is moot.

One imposes conservation laws to the ingoing and out going particles . Angular momentum is conserved once the Jz of the muon added to the Jz of neutrino is zero. In the center of mass system shown in the middle picture it means that the J of the two particles must also be oriented equal and opposite so as to match the J=0 of the pion. This constraint will be included in the integral for calculating the decay rate, which the Feynman diagram represents.

Comment: Since pion is a bound state, so could it be that the pion first goes to a state of angular momentum 1 before going to the final state via W+ channel?

Comment: The pion is a bound state of an up and antidown with spin 0, i.e. the spins of the quark is opposite to the spin of the antiquark and there is no angular momentu ( l=0, S state). Due to the existence of the weak interaction the 1/2 spin quark(antiquark) line can go to the lower ground state of an  antilepton( mu+) and a neutrino , conserving lepton number. In the virtual path as I said energy momentum are not conserved ( off mass shell) and the same happens with angular momentum, it is not a conserved quantity within a virtual line. One should look for conservation btetween input output lines

Comment: The pion is pound by the strong interaction. The decay is due to the weak interaction.

Comment: Hmm.. but does the state l=1, S=0 exist for a bound state of up and anti-downquark ?

Comment: The pion has spin 0 so the probability of an l=1 state should be 0, though the QCD potential will not be of  a simple type. It is bound by the exchange of very many off mass shell gluons, but this is the collective angular momentum obtained. l=1 is a higher energy/mass,  the rho meson .

Comment: I was imagining bound state of quark and antidown quark as forming a kind of atom (like the hydrogen atom) with various angular momentum levels  of which pion is one state. But I am not sure if this picture make sense for strong interation

Comment: No, it makes no sense. The strong interaction is not, at these energies, like the electromagnetic . It is an observational fact that higher spin resonances are heavier, but it cannot be fitted with a simple potential model as it is a many body problem. to see the complexity in calculations look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD

Comment: I am pretty sure that although particles go "off shell", that momentum is still conserved at each vertex, and, similarly, charge, linear momentum, etc. I'm not really sure this answers the question at all...

Comment: @lionelbrits If energy and  momentum is conserved at the vertex going into W then W would not be off mass shell. It is conserved if you make a four particle vertex with no virtual in between.

Comment: @lionelbrits this was the old failed Fermi model of weak interactions, I vaguely remember, before quarks.

Comment: @lionelbrits  The virtual W there is representing the propagator that enters the integral which the Feynman diagram is a shorthand of. If the energy and momentum were conserved there would be no variable to integrate over since the mass would be fixed to the pi mass during the integration, and the momentum and energy will be fixed? what would be the variable?

Comment: There are no variables, because there are no loops. It's a tree level diagram.

Comment: You can conserve momentum and still be off-shell. Momentum conservation comes from the plethora of $e^{i (k-k')\cdot x}$ terms that go in the integrals. The point is that for virtual particles, you precisely integrate over a range of momenta ($\int\!dk\,$), not just the "shell" $k^2 = m^2$.

Comment: Momentum is conserved at every vertex, be it one with only real legs or not, and this is more than just semantics -- it is far from moot.

Comment: @GaloisFan I added that it is angular momentum conservation that is moot, though in grammar and syntax it should have been clear.

Answer (score 2):

The $W^-$ has to have zero angular momentum, since the $\pi^-$ does in its rest frame.  Since the $W^-$ has spin $1$, it must be in states of orbital angular momentum $1$ as well.  In particular, the spin-orbital states have to combine to give zero total angular momentum.  This specific combination is:

$$|+-\rangle+|-+\rangle-|00\rangle$$

where $+$ is $L_z$ or $S_z=+1$, $-$ is $L_z$ or $S_z=-1$, and $0$ of course is $L_z$ or $S_z=0$.

As a side effect, this proves that the pion can't be a point particle, something already known, because the $W^-$ in its p-state would have no chance of having been at the origin if the pion were a point particle.

Comment: I see a problem with the momentum of the W- being zero.  Not sure how to deal with it right now.  Off to the pencil and paper...  I'm going to use the muon-neutrino end rather than the pion end to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: You said that the W must be in a state of orbital angular momentum 1. W is not a composite particle. How can it have an orbital angular momentum? Orbital angular momentum between what and what?

Comment: In the simplest way of dealing with the hydrogen atom, the electron is the only particle there.  (The nucleus is treated as purely the source of potential energy.)  The electron can be in an l=1 state.  (Sorry, this seems not to let me insert newlines.  So continuing in another comment.)

Comment: Other than the issue of zero momentum, there is no problem of putting the W- in l=1 states, in the rest frame of the pion, for the same reason.  I suspect that the zero momentum issue is related to your questions.  I hope that applying the Feynman rules at the muon-W vertex should resolve the problem.  (We have to put the muon and neutrino into a state of zero total momentum and zero relative angular momentum.)

Comment: @JohnMorrison: your analogy with the hydrogen doesn't hold: the orbital angular momentum is between the electron and the proton. But for the W, contrary to the electron there is apparently nothing else with which it can have an orbital angular momentum (nothing equivalent to the proton).

Comment: Think of it this (classical) way: you have a particle (and nothing else) -- stationary or moving at constant speed in a straight line.  You can choose the coordinate system for the particle.  The natural choice is to place the particle at the origin: angular momentum is zero.  Another possibility is choose the origin and axes so that the particle moves on the x-axis: the angular momentum is still zero.  Finally, have the particle move parallel to the x-axis.  The angular momentum is the momentum x the impact parameter.  (Continued.)

Comment: @Paganini: In the case of a pi- becoming a W-, the natural frame is the rest frame of the pion.  Even when the pion disappears, the frame still exists.  The W- has to have l=1 in that frame, in order to have total angular momentum be zero.

Comment: @JohnMorrison: it doesn't make sense. First, your amplitude of the process would depend on the frame (the one that you choose to create artificially an angular momentum). Feynman diagrams are Lorentz invariant. Second, by choosing another frame, you do create some angular momentum, but you do it for all objects of the process: all particles would have $J' = J+L$ with $L$ the artificial angular momentum. So you can't explain an increase of angular momentum when moving from the pion to the W.

Answer (score -1):

Anna V gave the correct explanation. Only when weak bosons are created on mass shell, e.g. at collisions @ Ecm = M, can you apply total angular momentum conservation at a single vertex (production and decay). On the other hand, even for off mass shell bosons chirality (read helicity for ultra relativistic particles) imposses costraints at each vertex.